# Shape Builder Tool; Don't create extra anchor points

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, anchor-point

Is there a way to cut a shape using the *Shape Builder Tool* without it affecting the shape that is not supposed to be cut:

E.g. when I use an ellipse in order to cut a rectangle, I also get extra vertices on the ellipse, even though its shape essentially has not really changed:

[image: gif showing the process]

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think that's just the nature of it.

Comment: @WELZ I see ... is there some other way that lets me preserve the "original" shape without having to duplicate it every time beforehand? And if there isn't, is there some faster way to duplicate then using ctrl + c and ctrl + f / b?

Comment: To duplicate the shape, I use an action with the function key `F2`. (Action is just `Ctrl`+`C`, `Ctrl`+`F`)

Comment: THere is a technical reason it does this.if it wouldn't do this then theres no guarantee that the shapes could be the same.

Comment: Yup, merely how it works. Nothing you can do about it. I *always* duplicate, use pathfinder/shapebuilder, then use what I need from the results.

Comment: ah, ok. Thanks for the help guys / gals / attack helicopters.
what do I do with the stackexchange question? Shall I delete it or what is the standard procedure in such a case?

Comment: Also, @WELZ, when I look at the edit of my question it says the gif I added was removed and added again by your edit. Just for reference, did I do some wrong formatting when adding the GIF? Or does it just show it wrong in the "edit log" (or whatever that screen is called :D)

Comment: There are some flaws in the revision history. GIF is perfect.

Comment: I think you should leave the question, maybe one day there will be a solution or something.

Comment: @WELZ, ah, I saw it in the side by side markdown view. You edited the picture description to fit with the rest of your corrections, that's why it was marked that way. So nvm haha xD